# How can I automatically generate sprites for my less file?

Tags: css, less

I have a project with `less` files which reference images via URLs. The project is delivered to the user as a single page application, with all JS minfiied and sent as one file. However, images are sent in separate files. To eliminate this latency, I want to deliver the images in one file. How can I (in a non-manual manner) sprite the images, and alter the `less` to refere to the sprited images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate your sprite CSS selectors into their own file that's generated at the same time as your sprite sheet. I use [SpriteRight](http://spriterightapp.com) but there any many ways to skin that cat. Here's a command line tool called [Glue](http://glue.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) if you prefer that. Once you have your sprite Less/CSS file you then import it back into your main Less file, and it should work.

So your setup might look like this:

- /less

  - main.less
  - sprite.less
- /css

  - main.css (compiled & concatenated Less files)
- /img

  - /_for-sprites

    - ... (the images that comprise your sprite sheet)
  - sprite.png

main.less:

```
... (snip) ...
@import 'sprite.less';
... (snip) ...
```

sprite.less (generated by a utility as linked above):

```
... (snip) ...
.icon1 { background-position: 0 0; }
.icon2 { background-position: 20px 20px }
... (snip) ...
```

I hope my explanation makes sense. I do something very similar to this every day and it works great.

Comment: Unfortunately Glue and suggested solution with SpriteRight is not working anymore.